# Workflow to send 1 email for multiple items with the same value (dont want multiple emails)

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow

Hi guys I have a SharePoint list, where a few fields in the list have the same value, Id like to have a workflow send an email to the creator, but I don't want multiple emails for every item that was created by them and have the same value in REQStatus field which will change from multiple status fields.

Example:

I have a form with a repeating table, which can submit unlimited items to a list. So lets say 1 form has 5 items it submits to a list, each of those 5 items will have the same "REQNumber" and all five items will have the same status so "REQStatus" when REQStatus changes to Ordered I want an email to go out basically saying hey "REQNumber XXX" has been ordered. But I don't want them to get 5 different emails, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this approach :

Add a web service HTTP call activity to your workflow.

Using this activity, make an HTTP call to your Sharepoint list.

The URL should looks like this :

http://yoursite/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/yourlist?$select=REQStatus&$filter=(REQNumber eq 'CurrentElementReqNumber' and REQStatus eq 'Ordered')

Notice that the URL contains a filter to returns only items that match the current element REQNumber and that has a REQStatus Ordered.

If this request returns no results, send an email.

In the other hand don't send an email.

Comment: Is this only available in 2013? I only have SharePoint 2010 and Designer 2010... can designer 2013 work with SharePoint 2010?

Comment: Between 2010 and 2013 version of SharePoint release, there have been big changes. I do not had the chance to create very sophisticated workflow with Sharepoint 2010. I therefore can not confirm if it is possible to achieve what you want if you are using the 2010 version of Sharepoint.

Comment: Yeah, it appears that feature from what I find on searches is only available for SharePoint 2013 a "loop through" feature is what most people are calling it.